# Passing functions with Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I am using Jetpack Compose for Android Native with Kotlin in a project I am building. I’m running into a situation with Kotlin that I don’t quite understand. I don’t think the issue has anything to do with Jetpack, I think it’s more Kotlin related.

I’m trying to build a generic component that can be used for all different objects that subclass the same superclass. Some of them have added fields and behaviors. So I’m trying to pass in different functions to deal with the differences.

Here is the function signature of my component:

```
fun TwistyCard(
    cardItem: CardItem,
    childItemList: CardItemList? = null,
    triggerRerenderFunc: () -> Unit = {},
    checkedFunc: () -> Boolean = { false },
    clickExpandFunc: (CardItem, CardItemList?) -> Unit = {
        cardItemToExpand: CardItem, cardItemListToExpand: CardItemList? ->
    },
) {
```

I want to be able to call the `TwistyCard` with a function `clickExpandFunc` to which I will pass the `CardItem` and `CardItemList` objects.

The first thing I don’t understand is why I can’t initialize the function to `{}`, because for most of the `CardItem` types, this function will not be used. It forced me to enter what I have above to get rid of syntax errors. I don’t think this is a big deal, but it’s something I obviously don’t understand.

Later in this `TwistyCard`, I will call this function like this:

```
clickExpandFunc(cardItem, childItemList)
```

My problem comes in when I try to use this from one of my other components. Here’s my implementation of the `clickExpandFunc`:

```
fun clickExpand(cardItem: CardItem, cardItemList: CardItemList?) {
    if (CardItemList.isEmpty(cardItemList)) {
        return
    }
    val locationType = (cardItemList!!.itemList.first() as Location).type
…
}
```

I call TwistyCard, passing in the function from above:

```
TwistyCard(
    cardItem = game,
    childItemList = childItemList,
    triggerRerenderFunc = { locationViewModel.triggerLocationListUpdate(true) },
    checkedFunc = { areAllLocationsForGameChosen(gameName, locationType) },
    clickExpandFunc = { clickExpand(game, childItemList) },     <<<<< SYNTAX ERROR HERE
)
```

However, the above code gives me a syntax error:

```
Expected 2 parameters of types CardItem, CardItemList?
Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but (CardItem, CardItemList?) -> Unit was expected
```

I do not understand why it thinks I’m passing in `() -> Unit`. This makes no sense to me. What do I need to change to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same reason for both cases. If we define a lambda without specifying its params, that means it is either parameterless or it accepts a single argument. In your case we need a lambda accepting two params, so we can't define it as `{}` or `{ /* body */ }`. We need to specify its params: `{ p1, p2 -> /* body */ }`.

In the first case you can use `_` which means to ignore the param:

```kotlin
clickExpandFunc: (CardItem, CardItemList?) -> Unit = { _, _ -> }
```

In the second case you need to properly receive and pass params:

```kotlin
clickExpandFunc = { cardItem, cardItemList -> clickExpand(cardItem, childItemList) },
```

You could simplify this specific case to:

```kotlin
clickExpandFunc = ::clickExpand
```